# How to highlight line and all point in echarts

Tags: echarts

I am using echarts with Vuejs. Behavior of chart is hover line. Line will be highlight and all point will be show like this.
[image]
*default*
[image]
*when mouse hover*

I try to use option `emphasis` of series of type `line`. But it make only highlight line. not work for item style. like this
[image]
I want to default the all point not show. and all point will be show when emphasis active. But document of echarts not mention of this issue. Here is my config:

```
        itemStyle: {
          color: '#fff',
          borderColor: color,
          borderWidth: 3,
          opacity: 0,
        },
        lineStyle: {
          width: 2,
          color,
        },
        emphasis: {
          focus: 'series',
          lineStyle: {
            width: 3,
          },
          itemStyle: {
            shadowBlur: 9,
            shadowColor: color,
            opacity: 1,
          },
        },
```

With any idea, please give me advice. Thanks so much